# VMware Workstation shared folder takes Fedora disk space

Tags: fedora, mount, vmware-workstation

I have a Fedora guest hosted on Windows 8.1 using VMware Workstation 10.0.5. I need to share a large (~30 GB) network drive with the guest vm so that I can do calculations with the data available through this drive. I came back to my vm today only to find warnings about over usage of disk space. Analyzing the disk space with `baobab` showed that my `mnt` (mount) directory was to blame. I copied some important data to the local home directory and unmounted the drive to find that all disk usage went back to normal. Remounting the drive did not exhibit this problem.

The guest OS is fully up to date with a `yum update`, and the vmware tools are installed using the necessary patches for the latest kernel. I would like to know what could have caused this bizarre behavior, so that I do not cause it again. I have attempted to repeat it, but have been unsuccessful so far. My fear is that it could cause problems to my virtual machine with the potential for loss of data. It is unclear if the guest mistakenly calculated disk space or if vmware moved the shared folder contents into the virtual disk in the background. Either way, the result was not desirable.

**Edit**

It may also be relevant that I have soft-links in my main filesystem that link to the mounted file systems. Although, it would be strange to count this towards the main file system disk usage.

Comment: What exactly did the warning say? I

Comment: I did not write it down, but I think it essentially warned me of low disk space on Filesystem `/`

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't low space on `/mnt`